# JList is not Showing Up

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jlist

```
private static void initGUI(char[][] code){
    
    int width = (int) (code[0].length * new JLabel().getFont().getSize2D());
    int height = (int) (code.length * new JLabel().getFont().getSize2D()) + 200;
    
    gridgui = new JLabel[code.length][code[0].length];
    for(int x = 0; x < code.length; ++x){
        for(int y = 0; y < code[0].length; ++y){
            gridgui[x][y] = new JLabel();
            gridgui[x][y].setText(""+code[x][y]);
            gridgui[x][y].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            gridgui[x][y].setOpaque(true);
        }
    }
    listModel = new DefaultListModel<Integer>();
    listModel.addElement(5);

    //Create the list and put it in a scroll pane.
    stacklist = new JList<Integer>(listModel);
    JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(stacklist);
    listScrollPane.getViewport().setView(stacklist);
    
    frame = new JFrame("Befunge 93! Wow!");
    
    gridpanel = new JPanel();
    gridpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(gridgui.length, gridgui[0].length));
    gridpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    
    for(int x = 0; x < gridgui.length; ++x){
        for(int y = 0; y < gridgui[0].length; ++y){
            gridpanel.add(gridgui[x][y]);
        }
    }
    
    stackpanel = new JPanel();
    stackpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(100, height));
    stackpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    stackpanel.add(listScrollPane);
    
    
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    container.add(gridpanel);
    container.add(stackpanel);
    
    frame.add(container);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I would have put less and more compact code, but I honestly have no clue where the problem could be.

The issue is that the items in the JList `stacklist` don't show up. It just looks like this: [image: JList]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/8b38/b0wucudzpgl46yofg.jpg))</sub>
(with the arrow pointing to the JList)

I've been troubleshooting this for hours and I fear it's something painfully obvious that will cause my to quit programming forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to understand how `GridLayout` works...

```
stackpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(100, height));
```

Basic says, create me a grid which has 100 rows and `height` number of columns...This is reserving space for each cell...

If I change it to...

```
stackpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(code.length, 1));
```

I get...
[image: codes]

But I'm only guess at what it is you're trying to achieve...

You should also avoid using `setPreferredSize` where you can

Comment: Oh my god, this is why I love this site... Thank you! Also, what should I use instead of `setPreferredSize`?

Comment: That depends on which component you're dealing with.  Generally, you should simply let the components determine there preferred sizes.  You can use `JList#setVisibleRowCount` to effect the number of rows which are visible in a `JList`, which effects the size of the parent `JScrollPane` or use things like `EmptyBorder` if you want to add some additional space around components

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi has some information about using or not using `setPreferredSize` (I think I learned a lot from that question).